# Is it safe to smoke a 20lb turkey?

Tags: turkey, smoking

I just spatchcocked a 12 lb turkey, smoked it in temperature around 225-275 F (107-135 C) for about 3 hours. I did it in a kamado joe classic 3 with SloRoller.  It came out amazing. Fully cooked, tender and flavorful

I’m wondering
Is it possible to do the same thing with a 20lb turkey?

Some random sources I googled suggested that that’s crossing into the “danger zone” anything above 12lb.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main concern with smoking large **whole** turkeys is that heat may not get into the cavity, so the inside may not get up to temperature fast enough. When you spatchcock a turkey the heat can get to both sides evenly, so you take away this problem and a 20lb turkey should be fine. Kamado Joes (I have a Classic 2) have excellent heat circulation so I wouldn't expect you to have a problem with a whole one, but spatchcocking will give you better results.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can smoke a 20lb turkey. I have never had to spatchcock one, but I do not have a rotator or one of the premium smokers mentioned either. I have a simple "locker style" smoker (vertical with a propane burner). That said, I never have any problems with even the largest bird. My caveat here is that I leave the body fully open (i.e. no stuffing).

The key here is to not aim to fully cook the bird in the smoker itself. I typically smoke it at about 4 hours at 225 F. That should bring the bird to about the 150 F range. I then heat the oven to 400 F and pull the bird out into a baking pan. Cover the top with foil (leave the meat thermometer in) and put the bird in the oven for another 15-30 mins. That should bring it to your desirable 160 F.

I've done this for several years and get a perfect bird every time.